# Two different computers with one Microsoft account

Tags: windows, windows-8, resolution, scaling

I recently bought a 13 inch 1920x1080 laptop. If I set the default scaling to 100% in Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalisation -> Display, it's too small to be usable. I set it to 125 % and it looks good.

Today I checked my desktop PC with 1680x1050 resolution screens. It has the same scaling as the laptop though in Control Panel it says it's 100 %.

How do I change it on the desktop PC?

After I noticed this I changed the synchronizing settings and disabled options to synchronize desktop backgrounds and such. I restarted both PCs but no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to select different theme? it's the usual right-click on Desktop -> Personalize

On the Desktop make sure "synced theme" is **not** selected. Restart/log-off just in case.

If nothing appear to fixed the problem. I'd try to re-create a new user with fresh settings.
Since you have disabled the theme sync on your laptop, the new account on desktop shouldn't sync anything at all including the DPI settings.